# 304 not modified with url starting with https.How to fix?

Tags: php, html, apache, magento, http-headers

I am having a magento site.This site works well with http url.But when the url starts with **https**, I find errors in net panel of Firefox like:

Get my_image.jpg **304Not Modified**.

Due to this some images are not loading.If I reload the page with http:// url everything works well.

What may be the issue?
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The 304 Not Modified means the browser knows it has a copy of the image file in its cache and is using an If-Modified-Since header in its HTTP GET to the server to see if the image file has changed on the server.  The server is replying with a 304 saying that the file has not been modified.

As for the image not displaying, check to see if you have any settings in the browser that prevent unencrypted content from being displayed with encrypted content.  If so, the browser is hiding the image because it's not available over https.  Just a guess on this one.